# How to create and populate pandas columns based on cell values

Tags: pandas, count, frequency, calculated-columns

I have created a dataframe called `df` as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'feature1': [1, 22,45,78,78], 'feature2': [33, 2,2,65,65], 'feature3': [100, 2,359,87,2],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
print(df)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

[image]

I want to create two new columns called `Freq_1` and `Freq_2` that count, for each record, how many times the number `1` and number `2` appear respectively. So, I'd like the resulting dataframe to look like this:

[image]

So, let's take a look at the column called `Freq_1`:

- for the first record, it's equal to 1 because the number `1` appears only once across the whole first record;
- for the other records, it's equal to 0 because the number `1` never appears.

Let's take a look now at the column called `Freq_2`:

- for the first record, Freq_2 is equal to 0 because number `2` doesn't appear;
- for second record, Freq_2 is equal to 2 because the number `2` appears twice;
- and so on ...

How do I create the columns Freq_1 and Freq_2 in pandas?

Comment: For the second record, what should `Freq_2` be? The digit `2` appears in 3 features but there are 4 digits on the row

Comment: So, for the second record the digit 2 appears twice: once for feature2 and once for feature3. Hence the newly calculated feature (Freq_2, which counts how many times the digit 2 appears across feature1 and feature2) is equal to 2.

Comment: Ah I misread your question. See my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```py
freq = {
    i: df.eq(i).sum(axis=1) for i in range(10)
}

pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(freq).add_prefix("Freq_")], axis=1)
```

Result:

```
 feature1  feature2  feature3  Freq_0  Freq_1  Freq_2  Freq_3  Freq_4  Freq_5  Freq_6  Freq_7  Freq_8  Freq_9
        1        33       100       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
       22         2         2       0       0       2       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
       45         2       359       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
       78        65        87       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
       78        65         2       0       0       1       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: Nice.  Instead of a range could also build the dictionary with whatever values occur:   `for i in sorted(df.unstack().unique())`

Answer (score 1):

String pattern matching can be performed when the columns are casted to string columns.

```
d = {'feature1': [1, 22,45,78,78], 'feature2': [33, 2,2,65,65], 'feature3': [100, 2,359,87,2],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df = df.stack().astype(str).unstack()
```

Now we can iterate for each pattern that we are looking for:

```
usefull_columns = df.columns
for pattern in ['1', '2']:
     df[f'freq_{pattern}'] = df[usefull_columns].stack().str.count(pattern).unstack().max(axis=1)
```

Printing the output:

```
  feature1 feature2 feature3  freq_1  freq_2
0        1       33      100     1.0     0.0
1       22        2        2     0.0     2.0
2       45        2      359     0.0     1.0
3       78       65       87     0.0     0.0
4       78       65        2     0.0     1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
s = df.where(df.isin([1,2])).stack()
out = df.join(pd.crosstab(s.index.get_level_values(0),s).add_prefix('Freq_')).fillna(0)
Out[299]: 
   feature1  feature2  feature3  Freq_1.0  Freq_2.0
0         1        33       100       1.0       0.0
1        22         2         2       0.0       2.0
2        45         2       359       0.0       1.0
3        78        65        87       0.0       0.0
4        78        65         2       0.0       1.0
```